# How to display 0-nth character in a file name

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a file = 'test_acn_mark_down_201400000.csv'.
I wanted to have a value only file1='test_acn_mark_down' in unix
which means from position 0 to f4 and the delimiter will be '-'.

Please help me .

Comment: The delimiter is not `'-'` in your output sample. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut`:

```
file='test_acn_mark_down_201400000.csv'
echo "$file" | cut -d _ -f1-4

file1=$(echo "echi $file" | cut -d _ -f1-4)
echo "$file1"
test_acn_mark_down
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for the first four fields.
The best way will be using cut:

```
file=test_acn_mark_down_201400000.csv
file1=$(echo "${file}" | cut -d _ -f1-4)
```

When you know that the remaining part of the filename is without '_' characters, you can also use a special syntax removing everything on the end starting with the last underscore:

```
file=test_acn_mark_down_201400000.csv
file1="${file%_*}"
```